# Why can't I receive the request query in for my delete request?

Tags: javascript, node.js

There is no response in the `console.log` when I run this code, but I don't understand why?

```
        async function deleteUser(){
            const deleteUser = await fetch(`http://localhost:8000/restApi/userModel/delete?acc=${id}`)
        }


        router.delete('/delete', async (req,res)=>{
            console.log(JSON.stringify(req.query))

        })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default method of `fetch` is a GET request, but on your router you've only specified behavior for a DELETE request.

Not sure which fetch module you're using, but it may have a shortcut such as `fetch.delete(url)` - check the docs to be sure. You can also simply change the expected method to a GET with `router.get('/delete', ...`, but I wouldn't recommend this - it would make more sense for an API to not have a `delete` route, but rather just a route where GET returns the object and DELETE deletes it.

Comment: The available [request types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) and their uses, if you're not aware.